# How can i make it so money goes up instead of repeating?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So i'm creating a 2D game in unity using c#. Right now when i play the game and i pickup a gem money goes from 0 to 1 and if i pickup another gem it does 0 to 1 again, i'm not sure why it keeps going back to 0. What do i change to make it  so when i pickup gems the money does increase and make sure it works with the savesystem. I have 4 scripts: GemPickup, Player, Playerdata and SaveSystem.

Please help as I need to sort this out soon as i have to finish the game by end of November.

GemPickup Script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Gempickup : Player
{
    public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D Collision)
    {
        if (Collision.gameObject.tag.Equals("Player"))
        {            
            Destroy(gameObject);
            money = money + 1;
        }        
    }
}
```

Player Script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int level;
    public int health;
    public int money;

    public void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("k"))
        {
            SaveSystem.SavePlayer(this);
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown("l"))
        {
            PlayerData data = SaveSystem.Loadplayer();

            level = data.level;
            health = data.health;
            money = data.money;

            Vector3 position;
            position.x = data.position[0];
            position.y = data.position[1];
            position.z = data.position[2];
            transform.position = position;
        }
    }
}
```

PlayerData script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
public class PlayerData
{
    public int level;
    public int health;
    public int money;
    public float[] position;

    public PlayerData(Player player)
    {
        level = player.level;
        health = player.health;
        money = player.money;

        position = new float[3];
        position[0] = player.transform.position.x;
        position[1] = player.transform.position.y;
        position[2] = player.transform.position.z;
    }
}
```

SaveSystem script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

public static class SaveSystem
{
    public static void SavePlayer (Player player)
    {
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/player.fun";
        FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);

        PlayerData data = new PlayerData(player);

        formatter.Serialize(stream, data);
        stream.Close();
    }

    public static PlayerData Loadplayer()
    {
        string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/player.fun";
        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);

            PlayerData data = formatter.Deserialize(stream) as PlayerData;
            stream.Close();

            return data;            
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("Save file not found in" + path);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is `gempickup` not part of the `player` class? If you derive `gempickup` from `player` and create a `gempickup` object, the `money` object within the `gempickup` object is not linked to the `player` object.. And there's a `money` object in both `player` and `playerdata`?! You should really rethink your design and think where each object and function should be. But I'm afraid you're missing essentials on how C# works... you should start a simple tutorial... not start with unity.

Comment: You are incrementing money of the destroyed object, you should increment the money of the player...Agree with the @JHBonarius about the design...

Comment: if you make an instance of gempickup on each gem each one has its own  money variable all by default start at 0...

Comment: Thank you i removed the GemPickup script and put it in Player.

Answer (score 1):

try this in player script instead of attach script to gem gameobject. just add Gem tag to gem.

```
public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D Collision)
{
    if (Collision.gameObject.tag.Equals("Gem"))
    {

        Destroy(Collision.gameObject);
        money = money + 1;



    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Not to leave you hanging, and on a side-not that I don't use Unity, I jst want to show you the following code. This is how I would design it without unity.

```
public class Game
{

    public class GameObject
    {
        internal float[] position;

    }

    static public void Destroy(GameObject go)
    {
        // some object destruction
    }

    public class Gem : GameObject
    {
        // inherits position
    }

    public class Character : GameObject
    {
        // inherits position
        internal int health;
    }

    public class Enemy : Character
    {
        // inherits position and health
        public void OnCollision(GameObject other)
        {
            if (other is Player)
            {
                health--;
                if (health==0)
                {
                    Destroy(this);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    [System.Serializable]
    public class Player : Character
    {
        // inherits position and health
        // don't expose your internals
        // and probably should be properties.. but I don't know if they work with the serializer
        internal int level;
        internal int money;

        public void OnCollision(GameObject other)
        {
            if (other is Gem)
            {
                Destroy(other);
                money++;
            }
            else if (other is Enemy)
            {
                health--;
                if (health == 0)
                {
                    //game over;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nested classes like this isn't a good pattern, in Unity or not. Its not that it's inherently bad, but that it should only be done with good reason. And while you recognize that you don't use Unity, you didn't check to see what objects Unity supplies (such as GameObject) so you didn't have to specify them again. `GameObject` is also `final`; Unity developers are not supposed to (or allowed) to extend from it.

Comment: Yeah, this was juist a setup. Had some ideas which gave reason for inheritance, but they didn't add more value to this answer. Unity is different, but I'm not doing that